# Dynamically Create PDF file and Bind to Pdf Viewer control

Tags: c#, silverlight, telerik

I am generating an ssrs report in my *Silverlight* application and I need to convert the *ssrs report* to `RadPDFViewer control`(telerik silverlight). 
So I am saving the pdf file in the project folder using WCF. 
Now i need to read the file again and bind it to *Pdfviewer*.

Saving happens asynchronously. 
How should I wait untill the file is saved and then read from the folder?

Also, can you please show me how to read the PDF as a Memory stream.

I run the following code unsuccessfully.

```
public byte[] ReturnPdf(string requestUrl) {
        HttpWebRequest req = null; var buf = new byte[1024];
        try
        {
                req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);

                req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

                req.Method = "GET"; var objResponse = req.GetResponse();
                var stream = objResponse.GetResponseStream();
                if (stream != null){BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream);
                        buf = br.ReadBytes(1024);
                } if
                (stream != null) stream.Close();

        }
        catch Exception e){}return buf;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        string baseUrl = "http://abc/ReportServer&rs:Command=Render&rs:ClearSession=true&rs:Format=PDF";

        const string nullString = ":isnull=true";


        byte[] o = ReturnPdf(baseUrl);

        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        Stream s = new MemoryStream(bytes);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write PDF Stream:

[Write PDF stream to response stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828315/write-pdf-stream-to-response-stream)

You could check to see if the file has been written completely.

[How to test if a file is currently being written to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515766/how-to-test-if-a-file-is-currently-being-written-to)

Or this might help:

[How to check for file lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304/how-to-check-for-file-lock-in-c)

Comment: i have tried writhing the below code.. it still does not work. public byte[] ReturnPdf(string requestUrl)
        { HttpWebRequest req = null; var buf = new byte[1024];try{req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
     req.Method = "GET";
                var objResponse = req.GetResponse();
                var stream = objResponse.GetResponseStream();
if (stream != null){BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream);                   buf = br.ReadBytes(1024); }  if (stream != null) stream.Close();} catch Exception e){}return buf; }

Comment: There is no exception.. i just do not receice the PDF file.. is there any other way to do it>

Comment: Step through your code.  Stream is null, maybe?  Or PDF is null?  Turn off pop-up blocker?

Comment: You might use a combo of the free libaries PdfSharp and iTextSharp.  iTextSharp to read the file into a PdfSharp document and then stream to the browser.